# cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have in unit test code:

```
var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Create();
Assert.AreEqual("AddUnits", result.RouteValues["action"]);
```

But result.RouteValues["action"] gives me error:
**cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary**
I use ASP.NET MVC 4

Answer (score 8):

Although `RedirectToRouteResult` is defined in `System.Web.Mvc` assembly, `RouteValueDictionary` is defined in `System.Web` assembly (since it's part of the `ASP.Net Routing` mechansim that was introduced prior to the MVC framework).

Try to add a reference to `System.Web` in your test project and see if that helps.

Comment: What version of `System.Web` did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to System.Web.Routing

Answer (score 1):

You may be using MVC 5. 
If that is the case (which was my case), here is a solution, from [Unit Testing Controller Actions in MVC 5](http://blog.hovercraft.ie/post/66191253109) (part 4 - Using RouteValues dictionary):

> When trying to assert values returned within an action result we
>   utilise the `ActionResults` `RouteValueDictionar`, e.g.
>
> ```
> Assert.AreEqual(“Index”, result.RouteValues[“action”],“Unexpected View Name”);
> ```
>
> However, doing so in your MVC 5 unit test project may throw
>   the following compile error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ‘System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary’`
>
> Solution: Add System.Web.Routing 4.0 and System.Web 4.0 from the “Add
>   Reference” dialog. Routing is dependent on system.web. Add the
>   System.Web.Routing using declaration to your class file.

Your code should look like

```
var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Create();
Assert.AreEqual("AddUnits", ((RouteValueDictionary)result.RouteValues)["action"]);
```

Pay attention to the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference of System.Web to your test project. It help in my case.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the reference of "System.Web" and "System.Web.Routing" in your test Project. You can simply add it by right click on reference in test project.

Comment: This simply is a duplicate of earlier answers. Kindly refrain from posting an answer without new relevant / valuable content